# Can a person who just turned 18 reaffirm all contracts s/he has signed?

Tags: united-states, contract-law, minor

Suppose John Doe, who turned 18 today, had signed several contracts for non-essential purposes as a minor. If he makes a document saying something like "I, John Doe, hereby reaffirm and agree to be bound by any agreements into which I may have entered prior to my eighteenth birthday on August 16, 2022" available to the public online, does this make the agreements binding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The agreements are already binding

[Can a minor make a contract?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/58270/can-a-minor-make-a-contract/58279#58279)

John has a reasonable time after becoming an adult to void any ongoing contracts; if John continues to receive the benefit of or perform his obligations under any contracts he entered as a child after that reasonable time, they are no longer non-binding.

Such an announcement as you describe would not prevent John from voiding voidable contracts in the future. The people who theoretically benefit from the announcement have not given John any consideration for it so they cannot hold him to this promise.

Comment: End of first paragraph - should that be the other way round? After a reasonable time his voidable contracts are not voidable anymore?